# Pump Valve On/Off Regulation for Certain Time

Tags: fluid, dymola

In Switzerland, the heating period usually lasts from mid-September to mid-May.
Is there any possibility to set either valve or pump to closed (0 if y=true) position from e.g., 15.05 till 15.09 in the simulation?

Comment: Like the `valve` and `handle` in `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatingSystem` just with a longer simulation time? Potentially you would need to replace the `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Step` with a `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse` or `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable`...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest will be to use the `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression`as the RealInput to `Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible` component. You can assign `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression.y`= if (time > 15.05) and (time < 15.09) then 1 else 0.01. In `fluid`packages it is advisable not to set the valve close value explicitly as '0' but to positive value close to `0` say `0.01`.

[image]